# How do you enable Remote Connection with SQL Server 2008 w/o Installing Management Studio?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I'm having a rather tough time finding information on this since almost everything I read requires Management Studio installed in the server which I prefer not to do.

Also, to connect to it using SQL Server Management Studio installed on the client, are these settings ok?
ServerName: 10.232.234,1433\SQLEXPRESS
Login: sa
Password: password

Yes, I want to specify the port number in the client side since I have to go through a few firewalls which I have poke holes through to get to the SQL Default port 1433.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the SQLCMD utility to make the change on the command line from the server running the instance.  Information about SQLCMD can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165702.aspx).

The TSQL command you need to run is:

```
EXEC sys.sp_configure N'remote access', N'1'
GO
RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE
GO
```